# How can i automatically change the stock availability in Magento when the inventory is updated?

Tags: magento, e-commerce

We have a POS intergration set up to work with our Magento store. Stock figures are updated every few minutes. The issue that we are facing is that when an item goes out of stock (stock at 0), Magento sets the stock availability message to "Out of Stock". The problem is that when the stock figure is updated to a number greater than 0, Magento still shows the item as "Out of Stock", regardless of how many we now have in stock.

Is there a way to automatically change the stock availability message when an item is updated and comes back in stock?

Comment: What are you using to update the inventory?  API, Magento import, Magmi, something else? This will help provide you a more refined solution to your question.

Answer (score 1):

When a product in Magento hits a quantity of 0, the `is_in_stock` attribute is automatically set to `0`.

For your integration, you need to update the `is_in_stock` attribute to `1` if the quantity is greater than 0 upon import.